# Resources Permission's on a mac app get changed to "Custom" when building and archiving and creating package

Tags: cocoa, xcode, app-store

I am adding a help folder as a "folder reference" to my application that has several subfolders. When I build and run the application all is fine, I can access my help system ok.
But when I build and archive, create the signed installer package, (after installing using the installer package) I no longer have access to the subfolders on the help resource. The subfolder permissions change from "read only" to a "custom" privilage that does not allow the application to read its own resources.

Does anyone have any ideas what Im I doing wrong?
Thank you,
Jose.

Comment: Can you please list the results of running an `ls -la@1` on the directory in question? I happened to notice the same issue in another application I got from the Mac App Store (McSolitaire: 2 folders in Resources/themes couldn't be searched); perhaps there's a bug in Apple's code somewhere.

Comment: What does the @1 do?, On the installed folder - If I try the command on the parent folder it shows the following: .
..
101
HelpBundle.helpindex
Icon.jpg
contents
index.html
navindex.html
tocstyles.css
(All normal I think...) If I want to enter the folder it refuses with a permission denied (as expected)... I did a sudo -s, typed my password and enter the "Contents" folder (the one in question) after executing the command requested it displays:.
..
101
101.html
102
102.html
103
103.html
104
104.html
105.html
106.html
107.html
108.html
109.html
110.html
Icon.jpg
images
index.html
styles.css

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've checked with apple, the original folder did not had execute permission. Xcode needs the execute permission, you can set it by terminal or just set read & write permissions.